# Configure datadog cluster agent helm chart to include/exclude logs metrics etc

Tags: kubernetes-helm, datadog

I have been trying to play with datadog cluster agent to remove logs being sent to datadog that we don't need, and I am mostly failing so far.

This is the relevant part of my helm chart :

```
datadog:
  logs:
    enabled: true
    containerCollectAll: true
  containerInclude: "kube_namespace:<my_namespace>"
  containerIncludeLogs: "kube_namespace:<my_namespace>"
  containerIncludeMetrics: "kube_namespace:<my_namespace> kube_namespace:<my_namespace_2>"
  containerExcludeLogs: "kube_namespace:<my_namespace_2> kube_namespace:kube-system"
```

My goal is quite simple, yet I didn't manage to achieve it, I want to collect logs and metrics ONLY from <my_namespace>. I also want to exclude logs but collect metrics from <my_namespace_2>

This configuration does work, but includes much more than I'd like.

The documentation seems to indicate that I should set "ContainerCollectAll" to false which would make only included containers forward their logs.
The thing is, whenever I set "ContainerCollectAll" to false, I don't get any logs at all anymore no matter the rest of the configuration

Does anyone know how to set this properly or where I can find a proper documentation for this ?

I tried the following configurations :

```
datadog:
  logs:
    enabled: true
    containerCollectAll: false
  containerInclude: "kube_namespace:<my_namespace>"
  containerIncludeLogs: "kube_namespace:<my_namespace>"
  containerIncludeMetrics: "kube_namespace:<my_namespace> kube_namespace:<my_namespace_2>"
  containerExcludeLogs: "kube_namespace:<my_namespace_2> kube_namespace:kube-system"
```

No logs at all

```
datadog:
  logs:
    enabled: true
    containerCollectAll: true
  containerInclude: "kube_namespace:<my_namespace>"
  containerIncludeLogs: "kube_namespace:<my_namespace>"
  containerIncludeMetrics: "kube_namespace:<my_namespace> kube_namespace:<my_namespace_2>"
  containerExcludeLogs: "kube_namespace:*"
```

No logs at all

```
datadog:
  logs:
    enabled: true
    containerCollectAll: true
  containerInclude: "kube_namespace:<my_namespace>"
  containerIncludeLogs: "kube_namespace:<my_namespace>"
  containerIncludeMetrics: "kube_namespace:<my_namespace> kube_namespace:<my_namespace_2>"
  containerExcludeLogs: "kube_namespace:!<my_namespace>"
```

logs from all namespaces are being sent

I tried many other configurations, it seems I'm missing something regarding how the inclusion/exclusion configuration works

I used the helm chart reference here : https://github.com/DataDog/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/datadog#all-configuration-options

And the documentation here : https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/logs/advanced_log_collection/

I tried to use environment variables aswell but do not get better results

Answer (score 0):

I think `containerIncludeLogs` or `containerExcludeLogs` bind to container name not to other resource. You can try `containerExcludeLogs: "name:<container-name-that-you-want-to-exlude>"` and still set `containerCollectAll: true`

ref: https://github.com/DataDog/helm-charts/issues/131